# Why isn't there any command to start a paragraph with \vbox?

Tags: tex-core

`\vbox` does not switch modes and `\hbox` does not switch modes, as demonstrated by the following two groups of examples.

The following two examples produce identical output:

```
\hbox{A}
\end
```

```
\noindent A
\end
```

The following two examples also produce identical output:

```
\vbox{\hrule width 1em}
\end
```

```
\noindent\vbox{\hrule width 1em}
\end
```

---

Also, empty content switches mode from vertical to horizontal, as in `\unhbox\voidb@x`. That same empty content may be obtained via `\unvbox\voidb@x`. But using this does not switch mode from vertical to horizontal (see following two examples). Why?

```
\leavevmode\hbox{A}
\end
```

```
\catcode`\@=11
\unvbox\voidb@x\hbox{A}
\end
```

(Here in the first example indentation is added, and in the second not.)

`\vbox` may be inside paragraph, like `\hbox`. What control sequence may be used to create a `\vbox` in the middle as well as in the beginning of paragraph?

Comment: I'm not sure what the final question is about.  Do you mean something like this: `\def\parvbox{\ifvmode\leavevmode\fi\vbox}`?  That way a `\parvbox` can start a paragraph if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command for starting horizontal mode with a `\vbox` is `\leavevmode`. Why would you need something else?

Your assumption is wrong, I'm afraid: it's not “empty contents” that triggers mode change. It is *precisely* `\unhbox` that does.

Differently from `\box` and `\copy`, `\unhbox` is a horizontal command, so it triggers horizontal mode if TeX is in vertical mode. The macro `\leavevmode` uses `\voidb@x` so that nothing is appended to the horizontal list (after possibly having started it).

The analog command `\unvbox` is a vertical command and ***ends*** a paragraph.

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\leavehmode{\unvbox\voidb@x}
\catcode`@=12

\everypar{PAR}% to show a paragraph has started

abc\leavehmode def

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whether this is clear or not, but let's state it explicitly (from the TeXbook):

```
|\leavevmode| is an abbreviation for `|\unhbox\voidbox|',
where |\voidbox| is a permanently empty box register.
```

Now what does `\unhbox\voidbox` actually do?  Let's take a look in [`tex.web`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/580b76fb153c2c008128e6b77261d093a8730b83/texk/web2c/tex.web#L21081-L21088):

```
@ @<Cases of |main_control| that build...@>=
vmode+start_par: new_graf(cur_chr>0);
vmode+letter,vmode+other_char,vmode+char_num,vmode+char_given,
   vmode+math_shift,vmode+un_hbox,vmode+vrule,
   vmode+accent,vmode+discretionary,vmode+hskip,vmode+valign,
   vmode+ex_space,vmode+no_boundary:@t@>@;@/
  begin back_input; new_graf(true);
  end;
```

As you can see any of those combinations of mode and something else start a paragraph, but `vmode+un_vbox` is not among them.

On a personal note, I find it interesting that Knuth did not let `vmode+<*>vbox` start a paragraph but `vmode+valign` does.

Comment: It's in the same order as `vmode+<*>hbox` does start a paragraph but `vmode+halign` doesn't.